# token value based on date?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I'm currently in the process of deploying a ERC20 token with my symbol being CLC, and wondering if it's possible to change the value of the token based on the current date?

Basically splitting the value between phases?

```
1st August to the 20th August = 1CLC = $0.50
20th August to the 9th September = 1CLC = $0.75
9th September to the 6th October = 1CLC = $1.00
```

Would something like this be possible within a contract?

Comment: A way to modify value is to burn, and you could go about burning to provide deflation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `block.timestamp` variable in Solidity provides access to the timestamp of the current block in the blockchain (though note that miners can fudge this number by a bit). Using that value, your contract can calculate any logic it desires to adjust the pricing before/after certain date milestones.